# How to add a class active to the first foreach item?

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to add a class active to the first foreach a href in this loop

```
<!-- Gallery Filter -->
<div id="filter-by" class="clearfix">
    <a href="#" data-filter="gallery-item" class="active"><?php esc_html_e( 'All', 'framework' ); ?></a><?php
    $status_terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'property-status' ) );
    if ( ! empty( $status_terms ) && is_array( $status_terms ) ) {
        foreach ( $status_terms as $status_term ) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $status_term->slug, $status_term->taxonomy ) . '" data-filter="' . $status_term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all Properties having %s status', 'framework' ), $status_term->name ) . '">' . $status_term->name . '</a>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use a standard `for` loop instead

Answer (score 0):

assign a variable with the class string if it is NOT set

on subsequent iterations... when it IS set, then assign it to an empty string.

```
<!-- Gallery Filter -->
<div id="filter-by" class="clearfix">
    <a href="#" data-filter="gallery-item" class="active"><?php esc_html_e( 'All', 'framework' ); ?></a><?php
    $status_terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'property-status' ) );
    if ( ! empty( $status_terms ) && is_array( $status_terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $status_terms as $status_term ) {
            $class = !isset( $class ) ? ' class="my-class"' : '';
            echo '<a' . $class . ' href="' . get_term_link( $status_term->slug, $status_term->taxonomy ) . '" data-filter="' . $status_term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all Properties having %s status', 'framework' ), $status_term->name ) . '">' . $status_term->name . '</a>';
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what I've done is set a `$count` variable to check the loop is first or otherwise, if the loop has `$count = 0` then your class will be displayed or if the loop is second or more the class will not be displayed.

```
<div id="filter-by" class="clearfix">
    <a href="#" data-filter="gallery-item" class="active"><?php esc_html_e( 'All', 'framework' ); ?></a><?php
    $status_terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'property-status' ) );
    if ( ! empty( $status_terms ) && is_array( $status_terms ) ) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ( $status_terms as $status_term ) {
            $class = ($count == 0)?'class="active"':'';
            echo '<a '. $class  .' href="' . get_term_link( $status_term->slug, $status_term->taxonomy ) . '" data-filter="' . $status_term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all Properties having %s status', 'framework' ), $status_term->name ) . '">' . $status_term->name . '</a>';
            $count++;
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```